# What is the proper image size for an ePub cover page?

Tags: epub, image-scaling, cover, image-size

I am using the most excellent PHP library [ePub](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6115-PHP-Create-ebook-in-EPUB-format-for-ex-Apple-iPad.html) to on-the-fly create digital books from HTML stored in my database.

As these are part of a collection, I am including a cover image for every book.  Everything works fine in the code but depending upon the device/software interpreting the ePub, the image may get cut off.  I have seen 600x800 pixels as a recommended size, but it still cuts it off (for example in Aldiko in Android).  Is there a standard size that is recommended in the documentation?

Honestly, I would love a good and readable recommendation for documentation of the ePub format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it seems that Aldiko has the problem, and not the other e-Readers I have tested (Calibre, Overdrive).

After trying various ratios, I found that Aldiko only respects the `height:100%` style I have called out in the height direction.  It doesn't scale the image, only sets the height at 100% of the screen width.  I am going to have to go with this being a bug in Aldiko, and **keep the recommended 600x800 ratio** for maximum resolution.

Another interesting thing I discovered as well; the Aldiko reader didn't recover as well from non-standard HTML.  On one of the database entries, a `<style>` tag inside the `<body>` disappeared, but the style text did not.  This is not the same for the other e-Readers.

The best general advice I found on the internet is [Preparing Images for Ebooks Project (PIFEP)](http://zorbapress.com/?page_id=429).